# Why isn't my padding working? (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, cell, padding, cellpadding

On my website, I have created a sidebar. However, I want a padding of 40px between the content in the sidebar and the border of the sidebar. I have tried this but for some reason, it didn't work. What's going on?

My code:

```css
.sidebar {
  padding: "40px 40px 40px 40px";
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <form id="signUp" name="signUp">
        <p>
            <b>Hey!</b> Want to post comments and receive cool information about me? If You Do, Sign Up Now! :D<br>
            <br>
            Nickname: <input id="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" required="" type="text"><br>
            Email Address: <input id="email" maxlength="254" placeholder="Email Address" required="" type="text"><br>
            Password: <input id="password" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password"><br>
            <input onclick="confirmAccount" type="button" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: use `#sidebar` for id

Comment: still not working... Thanks for the suggestion though :D

Comment: `#sidebar {
  padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}`, that should fix it

Answer (score 2):

Using the correct selector (`#` instead of `.`) and removing the quotes and then this should work.

```css
#sidebar {
  padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <form id="signUp" name="signUp">
        <p>
            <b>Hey!</b> Want to post comments and receive cool information about me? If You Do, Sign Up Now! :D<br>
            <br>
            Nickname: <input id="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" required="" type="text"><br>
            Email Address: <input id="email" maxlength="254" placeholder="Email Address" required="" type="text"><br>
            Password: <input id="password" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password"><br>
            <input onclick="confirmAccount" type="button" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `"'s...

Try `#sidebar { padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px; }` instead.

Or you can just use `#sidebar { padding: 40px; }` as you need all sides padding 40px...

Comment: sorry bro... still not working. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your div has an `id` so use `#` instead of `.`. Second remove the quotes from the padding values - as they are all the same you can just use one `40px` value. The folllowing should work:

```
#sidebar {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Still not working... Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You have put .sidebar in your css style, which is a tag associated with a class (.).

For ids, such as your sidebar, always use a hash (#) to identify them in CSS. In this case you need to put #sidebar instead of .sidebar in your code.